# fsroot tree is invalid. All data still on disk but only 10% normally visible

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, apfs

I woke up today to start working on an audio project but upon loading I got some missing files errors. When I went to check, indeed, most of the folders I had shut the computer down with the night before were now not visible in the list. I ran Disk Drill and it is showing me everything (accessible and intact) as "Existing files" and being recoverable. They just aren't included by my file system in the list of folders any more. They are like ghost folders. I have one TimeMachine snapshot from July which works but it's too far back to be a satisfying solution. So I'm trying to figure out how I can fix the file system and get the folders back. Am operating on Mojave 10.14.5

```
192-168-0-184:~ warpedbiotic$ sudo fsck_apfs -d /dev/disk4s1
/sbin/mount_apfs -c -o rdonly /dev/disk4s1 /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/fsck_apfs.5465.1
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the space manager.
warning: spaceman main free count 703263987 does not match sum of free counts 703263974
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume SampleDB was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.260.7) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.260.7).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
error: drec_key object (oid 0x2): invalid hash (0, expected 8b785) of name (.Spotlight-V100)
obj-id: 2 type: DirRecord
file-id: 516044 flags: 4 date-added: 1644754926592177669 hash: 0x0 name-len: 16 name: .Spotlight-V100
fsroot tree is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk4s1 could not be verified completely.
```

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: 10.14.5 Mojave.

Comment: If Disk Drill can find them, then copy off to another drive before going any further.

Comment: Well it doesn't "find" them, the files are "there" as "Existing files". The file system just isn't showing them, I can just see like 10% of the folders.